# Vue components with width

Tags: vue.js

How do I combine this code into a single one?

`:width="isMobile ? '99%' : '200px'"` and `:width="isDesktop ? '99%' : '600px'"`

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you have to provide more information. What should happen if both `isMobile` and `isDesktop` is false?

Comment: Hi.
`<el-dialog :visible="visible" :width="isMobile ? '99%' : '600px'" @close="close" append-to-body class="user-select"></el-dialog>` code `isMobile` and `isDesktop` show size dialog.

Comment: We need more information. I'm not sure what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a directive that handles both, also you will be able to use it on all component.
eg:

```
directives: {
  responsiveWidth (el, binding) => {
    if (window.innerWidth > 1000)
       el.style.width = binding.value.desktop
    else el.style.width = binding.value.mobile
  }
}
```

and in your component

```
  <my-component v-responsive-width = "{ desktop: '400px', mobile: '200px' }" />
```